# Dynamically change image of an imageview in a thread

Tags: multithreading, image, dynamic, javafx-2

**Application:**

I'm trying to create a slide show inside my JavaFX application. To do this I created a thread and handle the image changes inside that thread. I use `Thread.sleep(int)` inside the thread to pause the transition between images.

**Implementation:**

I created the application in the Scene Builder so it's in FXML. The imageview starts out with an image and I gave the imageview an id. Here is a portion of the FXML where the imageview is located:

```
<Tab>
  <content>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="376.0" prefWidth="981.0">
           <children>
              <ImageView fx:id="myImage" fitHeight="197.0" fitWidth="294.0" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="151.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                 <image>
                    <Image url="@../Pictures/NevadaDesert.jpg" />
                 </image>
                 <effect>
                    <Glow />
                 </effect>
              </ImageView>
```

I am getting the imageview inside my Java code with:

```
@FXML
private ImageView myImage;
```

Then I handle all the image changes inside the new runnable thread which I call after loading the FXML:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MyResume.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    (new Thread(new PictureRunnable())).start();

}
```

The run method from PictureRunnable is shown here:

```
public void run() {

        try {


        File file1 = new File("C:/Users/Kyle/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyResume/src/Pictures/activities.jpg");
        File file2 = new File("C:/Users/Kyle/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyResume/src/Pictures/foodService2.png");
        File file3 = new File("C:/Users/Kyle/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyResume/src/Pictures/NevadaDesert.jpg");

        Image a = new Image(file1.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
        Image b = new Image(file2.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
        Image c = new Image(file3.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());

        for(int i=0; true; i++) {

    //Pause for 5 seconds
        try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }

            if( i%2 == 0 )
                myImage.setImage(a);
            else if( i%3 == 0 )
                myImage.setImage(b);
            else
                myImage.setImage(c);
        }

        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**

I'm getting a NullPointerException on the lines where I set the images `myImage.setImage(abc)`.

- Is there a problem in my code with how I'm changing the images?
- Or is the problem the thread, perhaps I cannot open a new thread and make changes to the Stage?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to work out why myImage is null.  Don't use a thread for this (you can't modify the active scene graph from your own thread), use a Timeline or Transitions.  Aside: your mod logic won't cycle the images evenly.  Study how [notzed wrote a slideshow](http://a-hackers-craic.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/javafx-slideshow.html).

Comment: You're right about the cycle I was trying to get a working mock up going before I refactored the code. Thanks for the comment it really helps.

Comment: @jewelsea the program from notzed doesn't work I just get a ton of exceptions. Did you ever try to run it and were you using Java8 like me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an image on an imageView it has to be on the javafx thread: use Platform.runLater() from your thread or some other mechanism.

I just noticed that my simple slideshow post has a few hits over its history - sorry it had a couple of bugs and the final release of java8 changed the way it handled null pointers in animations.  I've fixed those bugs and updated the post.

(i'm notzed)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: 0 down vote
 
I thought this was an answer to the question:
"If you want to set an image on an imageView it has to be on the javafx thread: use Platform.runLater() from your thread or some other mechanism.\"   I guess my help wasn't required though, got you.

Answer (score 0):

Using just java

```
package sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import java.lang.String;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;



public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int j = 0;
    JFXButton lbutton, rButton;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // images in src folder.
        try {
            list.add("/image/1.jpg");
            list.add("/image/2.jpg");
            list.add("/image/3.jpg");
            list.add("/image/4.jpg");
            list.add("/image/5.jpg");
            list.add("/image/6.jpg");
            list.add("/image/7.jpg");
            list.add("/image/8.jpg");

            GridPane root = new GridPane();
            root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            lbutton = new JFXButton("<");
            rButton = new JFXButton(">");

            Image images[] = new Image[list.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                images[i] = new Image(list.get(i));
            }

            imageView = new ImageView(images[j]);
            imageView.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);

            rButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                System.out.print("hello");
                j++;
                if (j > list.size()-1)
                {
                    j = list.size()-1;
                    imageView.setImage(images[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    imageView.setImage(images[j]);
                }
            });

            lbutton.setOnAction(e -> {
                System.out.print("hello");
                j--;
                if (j < 0)
                {
                    j = 0;
                    imageView.setImage(images[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    imageView.setImage(images[j]);
                }
            });

            imageView.setFitHeight(350);



          //main controls
          AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane(imageView, rButton, lbutton);
          AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(lbutton, 300.0);
          AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(lbutton, 210.0);
          AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(rButton, 300.0);
          AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(rButton, 210.0);

          // Set the stage
          Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
          imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
          primaryStage.setScene(scene);
          primaryStage.setResizable(false);
          primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
          primaryStage.show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```